# Microservices from inside a Kubernetes pod to access external database

Tags: kubernetes

I need a suggestion as right now I do not have a functional kube cluster.
We are building a set of microservices which will be running on the on-premise Kubernetes cluster. All these microservices have to access and external(to this clusetr) oracle database and a Kafka instances. Both the services(DB and Kafka) will be in the same network but outside Kubernetes cluster. This is a customer ask and we can't help it.

All I could understand from different posts are:
1. Create a Service yaml with Type as ExternalName and then have to provide the name(CNAME) accordingly.

My question is, can I use a IP instead of CNAME here ? Since the database is within the same network it seems obvious to me though.

Or do I have to add further configurations ?

I could search so many posts from developers who were not able to configure it properly. Hence, little doubtful about the exact step.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You mean "services inside a k8s cluster needs to access services outside the k8s cluster"? I don't think you need to create new "Service" in the k8s cluster. Why not  just acess them using IP directly? Need to modify DNS records if you want to use domain.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using an endpoint where you create an object that gives you a name inside the cluster that points to an external IP address.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: my-service
subsets: 
    - addresses:
          - ip: 192.0.2.42
      ports:
          - port: 9376
```

With that said the only point that remains is to be sure that the interna clúster network ranges don't conflict with your external network, because if you have for example on your cluster the range `10.0.0.0/8` for your pods and you use a subnetwork of that range also on the outside network for example `10.0.1.0/16` the pod should never reach the external service.